# draw borders on an online map

Tags: borders

I would like to split areas on a map of north germany between four community centers to split the responsibility for the whole map between these 4 areas.

Is there an online tool where I can draw the borders and store them so I can discuss the frontier?

I created a map with Gimp now, but that seems a bit complicated to change: https://github.com/rubo77/ffnord-community-borders

Comment: cartoDB might work for you, but a bit more information would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I tried now a bit with cartoDB, looks promising: 
https://rubo77.cartodb.com/tables/ffnord/map